# Who has a comma for a middle name?

Tags: code-golf, string

Your challenge is to take a name (string) as input, like

```
Albert Einstein
```

and output:

```
Einstein, Albert
```

### Pseudocode:

```
set in to input
set arr to in split by " "
set last to the last element of arr
remove the last element of arr
set out to arr joined with " "
prepend ", " to out
prepend last to out
output out
```

### More test cases:

```
John Fitzgerald Kennedy => Kennedy, John Fitzgerald
Abraham Lincoln => Lincoln, Abraham
```

### Rules

- The input will always match the regex `^([A-Z][a-z]+ )+([A-Z][a-z]+)$`.
- You don't need to handle [weird names](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/114927/whats-my-middle-name#comment280423_114927), even if the output is technically incorrect it is fine here.
- Trailing whitespace / newline is OK.
- Any questions? Comment below!

Comment: Are trailing spaces allowed?

Comment: I closed as dupe because solutions can pretty much siply replace `le` with `,` and you have this question

Comment: @Downgoat That challenge specifies two words, whereas solutions to this have to work for arbitrarily many words. As far as I can tell, of the answers with TIO links, only the [Seriously solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77712/61980) gives the correct answer for this question substituting `le` with `,`.

Comment: @Downgoat that one has -4. At least close that one as a dupe of this.

Comment: Are trailing spaces ok?

Comment: @TomCarpenter yes, they are.

Comment: @ngenisis that's not how duplicates work. These two questions are a textbook example of duplicates. I can drop in one more thing but they are still basically just the same challenge. Being duplicate isn't bad thing at all ether

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert phrases to reverse style](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77609/convert-phrases-to-reverse-style)

Comment: @WheatWizard https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/122322/who-has-a-comma-for-a-middle-name?noredirect=1#comment300099_122322

Comment: I still believe that it's a duplicate, however this challenge is better written and better received, so I have [closed the old challenge as a duplicate of this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/286591).

Comment: "The general rule is to **keep the question with the best collection of answers**, and close the other one as a duplicate."

Comment: Can we assume last names have at least 2 characters?

Comment: @Kevin yes, otherwise it wouldn't match the regex.

Comment: Ah yes, didn't notice the regex.

Comment: Johnny Comma Lately?

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

#### Code:

```
',ì#Áðý
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@6@uc3iN8uHGwxsO7/3/3zGpKDEjMVfBJzMvOT8nDwA)

#### Explanation:

```
',ì         # Prepend the input to ","
   #        # Split on spaces
    Á       # Rotate every element one position to the right (wrapping)
     ðý     # Join the array by spaces
```

Comment: Prepend! I knew there had to be a way to do it in listform.

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), 34 bytes

```
s=>s.replace(/(.+) (.+)/,'$2, $1')
```

## Demo:

```js
let f = s=>s.replace(/(.+) (.+)/,'$2, $1')

;[ 'Albert Einstein', 'John Fitzgerald Kennedy', 'Abraham Lincoln' ].forEach(
  s => console.log(`${s} => ${f(s)}`)
)
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>19</s> <s>17</s> 16 bytes

*Edit: Thanks to Riker for saving 3 bytes*

```
(.+) (.+)
$2, $1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6@hp62pACK4VIx0FFQM///3ys/IU3DLLKlKTy1KzElR8E7Ny0tNqQQA)

Comment: hold up, `(.+)` works too for both.

Comment: I don't understand why you were using `\w` in the first place

Comment: @theonlygusti I'm more familiar with pattern matching in Mathematica, which uses lazy matching rather than greedy.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
;”,Ḳṙ-K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/6UcNcnYc7Nj3cOVPX@//h9kdNayL//49W8srPyFNwyyypSk8tSsxJUfBOzctLTalU0lFQcsxJSi0qUXDNzCsuSc3MAwslFSVmJOYq@GTmJefn5CnFAgA)

I don't know Jelly very well, but reading other answers it looked like they didn't use an optimal algorithm... so here it is:

#### Explanation

```
;”,Ḳṙ-K
;”,        Append a comma to the end of the string
   Ḳ       Split on spaces
    ṙ-     Rotate the array by -1 (1 time towards the right)
      K    Join with spaces
```

Answer (score 6):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V) / vim, <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
$bD0Pa,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@6@S5GIQkKij8P@/V35GnoJbZklVempRYk6KgndqXl5qSiUA)

Saved one Byte thanks to

Note there is a trailing space character. Leaves a trailing space, which is allowed per the rules.

Explanation:

```
$       " move the cursor to the end of the line
 b      " move the cursor to the beginning of the current word
  D     " delete to the end of the line
   0    " move the cursor to the start of the line
    P   " paste in front of the cursor.
     a  " append (enter insert mode with the cursor one character forward)
      , " Literal text, ", "
```

Comment: Nice one! Good thinking putting the insert mode at the end to avoid needing `<esc>`. You can save one byte by doing `$bD` instead of `$diw`. :)

Comment: Thanks. `$bD` doesn't handle one-character names though, [I've asked OP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/122322/who-has-a-comma-for-a-middle-name/122509?noredirect=1#comment301044_122322) if that's allowed.

Comment: Looks like it is, so updating.

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica, <strike>52</strike> 40 bytes

```
StringReplace[x__~~" "~~y__:>y<>", "<>x]
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 39 bytes

```python
f,l=input().rsplit(' ',1);print l+',',f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FcixDoIwEADQ3a@4dCnEhoQV4@Cgg/IJLgUOe8l5NMcRoz9fwxvfJxEjtN2zzIHPJHmzqm50zUxWefChrU9ZSQz46IMPcynuviSBG9nvhRp5ggeK4PR1B3fhAdXgSrIakuwzaEzxDT3JuLC4Pw)

Yup, `rsplit`.

Comment: @UbdusSamad We allow Python's `input` instead of `raw_input` for golfing - see [this meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7634/65836)

Answer (score 5):

## Vim, 10 bytes/keystrokes

```
v$F dA, <esc>p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@1@m4qaQ4qijIF3w/79XfkaegltmSVV6alFiToqCd2peXmpKJQA)

Comment: Nice one, but I struggled to get it working, `<esc>` doesn't show up in your code. For notice to others who want to try: This assumes that the name is written in the editor and that you're currently at the beginning of the file in normal mode.

Answer (score 4):

## C, 45 bytes

EDIT: I just now noticed the requirement for the input possibly having more than two words. I'll leave it as-is with a note that this only works for two words.

EDIT: removed `\n`. Add 2 bytes if you consider it necessary.

```c
main(a,b)int**b;{printf("%s, %s",b[2],b[1]);}
```

Compiles with `gcc name.c`, GCC 6.3.1. Ignore warnings. Usage:

```c
$./a.out Albert Einstein
Einstein, Albert
```

Abuse of language:

- Implicit return type `int` of `main` and nothing returned.
- Implicit declaration of `printf`. GCC will include it anyway.
- Wrong type of `b`. Doesn't matter with `%s`

Thanks to @Khaled.K for the tips on using `main(a,b)int**b;` rather than `main(int a, int **b)`.

Comment: Nice first golf, welcome to the website, also `main(a,**b){printf("%s, %s",b[2],b[1]);}` is 40 bytes

Comment: Thanks :) I actually thought about omitting the types completely, but for some reason it wouldn't compile.

Comment: This works `main(a,b)int**b;{printf("%s, %s\n",b[2],b[1]);}`

Answer (score 4):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 27 bytes

```
i:0(?v
" ,"~<^r/
=" ":}o!/?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#@59pZaBhX8alpKCjVGcTV6TPZaukoGRVm6@ob///v2NSUWJGYq6CT2Zecn5OHgA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 22 bytes

```ruby
->s{s[/\w+$/]+", #$`"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#S7P9r2tXXF0crR9Trq2iH6utpKOgrJKgVPu/oLSkWCEtWsm9tLgksSxfwSexILOqKlEplgsm452TWFqs4JtYlJmo4FSUmJeSWJpapBT7HwA)

Answer (score 3):

## C, 68 bytes

Hope it's not wrong to add another post but here's a slightly different solution than my previously posted C solution. This one accepts any number of names.

```
main(a,b)int**b;{for(printf("%s,",b[--a]);--a;printf(" %s",*++b));}
```

Compile with `gcc name.c` (GCC 6.3.1) and ignore warnings. Usage:

```
$./a.out John Fitzgerald Kennedy
Kennedy, John Fitzgerald
```

Thanks to @Khaled.K for the tips on `main(a,b)int**b;`

Thanks for the tip on the for loop to @Alkano.

Comment: you can gain 2 bytes, by using for instead of while 
`main(a,b)int**b;{for(printf("%s,",b[--a]);++b,--a;printf(" %s",*b));}`

Comment: This sounds crazy, but you can do this `main(a,b)int**b;{a&&printf("%s,"b[a-1])&&main(a-1,b);}`

Comment: Very nice tricks :) I never thought about calling main recursively. But it doesn't quite work. It's output was "Kennedy,Fitzgerald,John,./a.out," A partial solution would be `main(a,b)int**b;{--a&&printf("%s, ",b[a])&&main(a,b);}`. It's 2 bytes shorter, and it makes sure you don't print the program name, but it still uses comma between each name.

Answer (score 3):

## sed, 19 + 1 for -E = 20 bytes

```
s/(.*) (.*)/\2, \1/
```

Must use -r (GNU) or -E (BSD, recent GNUs) to avoid having to escape the grouping parenthesis.

If written on the command-line, must be enclosed in quotes to avoid being parsed as multiple tokens by the shell :

```
sed -E 's/(.*) (.*)/\2, \1/'
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 45 bytes

```
#/.{a__,s=" ",b__}/;{b}~FreeQ~s->{b,",",s,a}&
```

Saved a few bytes over [ngenisis's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122329/56178) by taking input as a list of characters rather than as a string. Pure function that uses a pattern-replacement rule.

### Mathematica, 49 bytes

```
#~Join~{","," "}~RotateLeft~Last@Position[#," "]&
```

Another pure function taking a list of characters as input and returning a list of characters. This one appends `","` and `" "` to the input and then rotates the list of characters until the last space is at the end. (Thus the output has a trailing space, unlike the first function above.)

Comment: `#/.{a__,s=" ",b:Except@s..}->{b,",",s,a}&` is `4` bytes shorter, but I found out that the `Except` is unnecessary for string patterns, saving me `12` bytes.

Comment: ah, does it automatically choose the longest `x` in your answer?

Comment: Yep, string pattern matching is greedy but regular pattern matching is lazy.

Comment: nice <waves white flag>

Answer (score 2):

## C#, <s>76</s> 72 bytes

```c#
s=>System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s,"(.+) (.+)","$2, $1");
```

*Saved 4 bytes with the help of @KevinCruijssen*

Old version using substrings for 76 bytes:

```c#
s=>s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(' ')+1)+", "+s.Substring(0,s.LastIndexOf(' '));
```

Comment: Too bad `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` is so damn long in C#.. `s=>new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(.+) (.+)").Replace(s,"$2, $1");` is just one byte more.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen True but I can use the static method on `Regex` to save 4 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## Awk, 18 characters

```awk
{$1=$NF", "$1}NF--
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ awk '{$1=$NF", "$1}NF--' <<< 'John Fitzgerald Kennedy'
Kennedy, John Fitzgerald
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/awk#@1@tYmir4uempKOgpGJY6@emq/v/v1d@Rp6CW2ZJVXpqUWJOioJ3al5eakolAA)

Answer (score 1):

## JS (ES6), <s>52</s> 44 bytes

```
i=>(i=i.split` `,l=i.pop(),l+", "+i.join` `)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
Ḳ©Ṫ”,⁶®K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#AS0A0v//4biywqnhuarigJ0s4oG2wq5L////Sm9obiBGaXR6Z2VyYWxkIEtlbm5lZHk)

Comment: Damnit, Ninja'd and outgolfed.

Comment: @ATaco gg :) and that is a pretty big ninja.

Comment: (I was golfing, shhh)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
ḲµṪ;⁾, ;K
```

### Explained, ish:

```
ḲµṪ;⁾, ;K
Ḳ           # Split the input by spaces
 µ          # Separate the link into two chains. Essentially calls the right half with the split string monadically.
  Ṫ         # The last element, (The last name), modifying the array.
   ;        # Concatenated with...
    ⁾,      # The string literal; ", "
       ;    # Concatenated with...
        K   # The rest of the array, joined at spaces.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9qZWxsef//4biywrXhuao74oG@LCA7S////0pvaG4gRml0emdlcmFsZCBLZW5uZWR5)

[Try on all test cases.](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjk2Htj7cucr6UeM@HQVr7/@H2x81rYn8/z9aySs/I0/BLbOkKj21KDEnRcE7NS8vNaVSSUdByTEnKbWoRME1M6@4JDUzDyyUVJSYkZir4JOZl5yfk6cUCwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <s>110</s> 62 bytes

```
String d(String s){return s.replaceAll("(.+) (.+)","$2, $1");}
```

Non-static method.

-48 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

Comment: `String c(String s){int i=s.lastIndexOf(' ');return s.substring(i+1)+", "+s.substring(0,i);}` is shorter (**91 bytes**).

Comment: And `String d(String s){return s.replaceAll("(.+) (.+)","$2, $1");}` is even shorter (**62 bytes**).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Oh geez nice. Thanks! I should learn to use regex better :P

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
#`',«.Áðý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@6@coK5zaLXe4cbDGw7v/f/fKz8jT8Ets6QqPbUoMSdFwTs1Ly81pRIA)

**Explanation**

```
#           # split input on spaces
 `          # push each name separately to stack
  ',«       # concatenate a comma to the last name
     .Á     # rotate stack right
       ðý   # join stack by spaces
```

Comment: Yeah, I should probably make a join by space command :p

Comment: @Adnan: Would be nice seeing how often it's used :)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <strike>62</strike> 59 bytes

-3 bytes, thanks Jörg

```php
$a=explode(' ',$argn);echo array_pop($a).', '.join(' ',$a);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zVfdNzMovUsAg1a3/qyTaplYU5OSnpGqoK6jrgNVrWqcmZ@QrJBYVJVbGF@QXaKgkauqp6yio62XlZ@ZB1Wla//8PAA)

Old solution, 63 Bytes

Doesn't work if the person has 3 repeating names.

```php
<?=($a=strrchr($argv[1]," ")).", ".str_replace($a,'',$argv[1]);
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/php#@29jb6uhkmhbXFJUlJxRBGQWpZdFG8bqKCkoaWrqKekoKOkB5eKLUgtyEpNTgfI66uo6MFWa1v////fKz8hTcMssqUpPLUrMSVHwTs3LS02pBAA)

Comment: You can use `$argn` instead of `$argv[1]`

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB/[Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 37 bytes

```matlab
@(a)regexprep(a,'(.+) (.+)','$2, $1')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@gkahZlJqeWlFQlFqgkaijrqGnrakAItR11FWMdBRUDNU1/yfmFWuoO@YkpRaVKLhm5hWXZKbmAYUB)

Based on @ngenisis' Retina answer, we can also play the regex game in both Octave and MATLAB, saving a fair few bytes over my previous answer.

---

#### Old Answer:

I'm going to leave this answer here as well considering it is a more unique way of doing it compared to a simple regex.

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>49</s> 47 bytes

```matlab
@(a)[a((b=find(a==32)(end))+1:end) ', ' a(1:b)]
```

[Old try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@gkagZnaihkWSblpmXopFoa2tspKmRmpeiqaltaAWiFdR1FNQVEjUMrZJ0DTVj/yfmFWuoO@YkpRaVKLhm5hWXZKbmqWv@BwA)

An anonymous function to generate the output.

Basically the code first finds the last space in the string using `b=find(a==32)(end)`. Then It takes the end part of the string (after the space) using `a(b+1:end)`, where `b` is the output of finding the last space. It also takes the start of the string with `a(1:b-1)`, and concatenates both together with a `', '` in between.

I've already saved a few bytes vs the typical `find(a==32,1,'last')`. Not quite sure there is much more to save.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 45 Bytes

```php
<?=preg_filter("#(.*) (.+)#","$2, $1",$argn);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zVfLKz8hTcMssqUpPLUrMSVHwTs3LS02pVLLmsrf7b2NvW1CUmh6flplTklqkoaSsoaelqaChp62prKSjpGKko6BiqKQDNknT@v9/AA)

Comment: Why `\pL+` instead of `.+`?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen You are right the first part of the regex is greedy so it does not matter to use `.` or `\pL`

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](http://pyth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), 11 bytes

```
jd.>c+z\,d1
```

**Explanation:**

```
jd.>c+z\,d1
     +z\,      Append the "," to the input
    c+z\,d     Split the string on " "
  .>c+z\,d1    Rotate the array one element right
jd.>c+z\,d1    Join the array on " "
```

[Test it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jd.%3Ec%2Bz%5C%2Cd1&input=John%20Fitzgerald%20Kennedy&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 26 bytes

```bash
echo ${!#}, ${@:1:$[$#-1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@anJGvoFKtqFyrA6QcrAytVKJVlHUNY2v////vlZ@R998ts6QqPbUoMSflv3dqXl5qSiUA)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, <s>174</s> <s>170</s> 168 bytes

<sub><sup>Saved 2 bytes thanks to Wernisch</sup></sub>

```
=MID(A1,FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","^",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))+1,LEN(A1))&", "&LEFT(A1,FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","^",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")))))
```

This is not fancy or clever. It's a fairly basic method. It feels like there should be a shorter way with array formulas but I can't find one that works.

Comment: Solution only works for cases where there three names.  Does not handle "Albert Einstein" for example.

Comment: @Wernisch Thanks! It should work now.

Comment: Trailing whitespace is allowed according to question.  Think you can save 2 bytes by leaving out the the `-1` in the LEFT function.

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 14 bytes

```
U+', q'  é q'
```

A port of [@programmer5000](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58826/programmer5000)'s [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122324/58826).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@x@qra6jUKiuoHB4JYj6/1/JKzE3tVjBOSe1KFvBN7GiPDUnRwkA)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 52 bytes

```
lambda s:s.split()[-1]+", "+" ".join(s.split()[:-1])
```

Very simple, could use golfing help. Just puts the last word at the front and joins them with ", ".

Testcase:

```
>>> f=lambda s:s.split()[-1]+", "+" ".join(s.split()[:-1])
>>> f("Monty Python")
'Python, Monty'
>>> f("Albus Percival Wulfric Brian Dumbledore")
'Dumbledore, Albus Percival Wulfric Brian'
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl 18+1=19 bytes

```
perl -pe '/\S+$/;$_="$&, $`"'
```

+1 for `-p`

Answer (score 1):

## Vim, 6 keystrokes

```
i<C-p>, <End><C-w>
```

Leaves a trailing space character, which is allowed by the rules

Explanation:

```
i      Enter insert mode
<C-p>  Autocomplete with last word
,      Write ", "
<End>  Move the cursor to the end of the line
<C-w>  Delete the word behind the cursor
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `Ṡ`, 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
',+OṾ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSclMkMlMkJPJUUxJUI5JUJFJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9Sm9obiUyMEZpdHpnZXJhbGQlMjBLZW5uZWR5JmZsYWdzPSVFMSVCOSVBMA==)

##### Explanation

```python
',+OṾ  '# Implicit input
',+    '# Append a ","
   O    # Split on spaces
    Ṿ   # Rotate right
        # Join by spaces
        # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 7.5 bytes

```
*" "::`(\%$~","\
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWG7SUFJSsrBI0YlRV6pR0lGIgwlDZ_dFKMUpe-Rl5Cm6ZJVXpqUWJOSkK3ql5eakplTFKSrFQZQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `S`, 38 [bits<sup>v1</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 4.75 bytes

```
\,+⌈ǔ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJTPSIsIiIsIlxcLCvijIjHlCIsIiIsIkpvaG4gRml0emdlcmFsZCBLZW5uZWR5Il0=)

I do not have a comma for a middle name. Ports Thunno 2 but with a range coder.

```
\,+⌈ǔ­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‏​⁢⁠⁡‌­
\,+    # ‎⁡Append a comma
   ⌈   # ‎⁢Split on spaces
    ǔ  # ‎⁣Rotate right once
# ‎⁤The S flag joins on spaces
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, <s>52</s> 51 bytes:

```
k=input().split()
print(k[-1]+',',' '.join(k[:-1]))
```

-1 byte thanks to ovs

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 26+1 = 27 bytes

Uses the `-p` flag for +1 byte. Probably can be redone shorter in Retina. And it was!

-1 byte from Kevin Cruijssen.

```ruby
gsub /(.+) (.+)/,'\2, \1'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#Lcq9DoIwEADgnac4w4BGlOgbMOBQ3VxZ@nNpL2mv5igDvHyNics3fe1BVrPB5VP9shoYjtfzCX4MfTffe5hvXa1jNCgFJuKlIHGjcmB4UNk9io4OnsiMbmtGIzroBC9im@P/KW2zAUXsIwakhAJvGxK58gU)

Comment: `gsub /(.+) (.+)/,'\2, \1'` is one byte shorter.

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
44hYb1YSZc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@29ikhGZZBgZHJX8/7@6V35GnoJbZklVempRYk6KgndqXl5qSqU6AA)

#### Explanation

```
44h    % Implicitly input a string. Postpend a comma
       % STACK: 'John Fitzgerald Kennedy,'
Yb     % Split on spaces
       % STACK: {'John', 'Fitzgerald', 'Kennedy,'}
1YS    % Circularly shift 1 step to the right
       % STACK: {'Kennedy,', 'John', 'Fitzgerald'}
Zc     % Join with spaces between. Implicitly display
       % STACK: 'Kennedy, John Fitzgerald'
```

Answer (score 0):

## Gema, 23 characters

```
* =@append{s; *}
\Z=,$s
```

The only remarkable thing here is how the challenge managed to hit the weakness of the Gema patterns non-greediness.

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ echo -n 'John Fitzgerald Kennedy' | gema '* =@append{s; *};\Z=,$s'
Kennedy, John Fitzgerald
```

Answer (score 0):

## jq, <s>39</s> 38 characters

(<s>35</s> 34 characters code + 4 characters command line options)

```
./" "|last+", "+(.[:-1]|join(" "))
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ jq -Rr './" "|last+", "+(.[:-1]|join(" "))' <<< 'John Fitzgerald Kennedy'
Kennedy, John Fitzgerald
```

[Try in jq‣play](https://jqplay.org/s/Vsa99gnYef)

#### jq, 43 characters

(39 characters code + 4 characters command line options)

```
sub("(?<f>.+) (?<l>.+)";"\(.l), \(.f)")
```

Just a curiosity: `jq` only captures named groups, which helps readability, but nothing else.

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ jq -Rr 'sub("(?<f>.+) (?<l>.+)";"\(.l), \(.f)")' <<< 'John Fitzgerald Kennedy'
Kennedy, John Fitzgerald
```

[Try in jq‣play](https://jqplay.org/s/9cDQ36hgQ3)

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 65 bytes

```
(s:String)=>{val n=s.split(' ');n.last+", "+n.init.mkString(" ")}
```

Answer (score 0):

## R, 90 bytes

```
function(s){b=el(strsplit(s,' '))
l=length(b)
paste0(b[l],', ',paste(b[-l],collapse=' '))}
```

Anonymous function. Takes the string, splits it, outputs the last name, a comma, and the rest of the names from the beginning. Would love to see something better, I'm not too good at manipulating strings in R.

Answer (score 0):

## SNOBOL4, 77 bytes

```
begin
 input arb . f span(&lcase &ucase) . l rpos(0)
 output = l ', ' f
end
```

This is a pretty straightforward case of pattern matching.

1. Read a line of input, then match it against:
2. arbitrary characters (which we'll assign to `f`), followed by
3. a span of upper- and lower-case letters (which we'll assign to `l`) which
4. matches to the end of the input (`rpos(0)`).

Having matched those, we write out `l`, comma and space, `f`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Carrot](https://github.com/kritixilithos/Carrot/), 56 bytes

```
#^//\w+$|^.+(?= )/gS";"^ ^*1//;.+(?=;)/S0-1//^\w+| .+$/g
```

[Try it online!](http://kritixilithos.github.io/Carrot/)

#### Explanation

Carrot has several global variables, one for each type: string, float and array. The program starts in string-mode, where all the operators will affect the global string variable. And I call these variables the "stack".

Example input is `John Fitzgerald Kennedy`.

```
#^                       Set stack-string to the value of the input string
/                        Operator, get matches of this regex on the stack-string and store the matches in stack-array
 /\w+$|^.+(?= )/g        The last name or the first names
S";"                     Convert to string-mode by joining on ";"
                         stack-string = "John Fitzgerald;Kennedy"
^ ^                      Append a space to the stack-string
*1                       Append one copy of the stack-string to itself
                         stack-string = "John Fitzgerald;Kennedy John Fitzgerald;Kennedy "
/                        The match operator
 /;.+(?=;)/              Anything bounded by ";"s except for the last ";"
S0                       Since we are guaranteed to get one match, we can join with any literal, it does not matter. Here we are joining using a 0.
-1                       Remove the first character in the stack-string (the first ";")
                         stack-string = "Kennedy John Fitzgerald"
/                        The match operator
 /^\w+| .+$/g            The first word or the last ones
                         stack-array = ["Kennedy", " John Fitzgerald"]
```

Luckily for us, the interpreter is bad and displays the result as just `Kennedy, John Fitzgerald`.

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell, 35 Bytes

simple regex solution, not too interesting:

```
"$args"-replace'(.+) (.+)','$2, $1'
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), <s>21</s> 17 bytes

```
,p p
'@'p
pQ$d
r-
```

<s>I'm *sure* we can fit this into a 4x4, but I just couldn't do it..</s>

Reads a value, splits it on whitespace, "unqueues" it (a b c -> c a b), prints the first element, prints a comma, sets a catchmark.

Prints a space and the next element (i.e. the first given name). Duplicate the top stack element (a zero if we're done, otherwise the next given name). If that value is truthy (i.e. not 0), jump to the catch mark.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 49+1 bytes

```php
<?=preg_replace("#^(.*) (\w+)$#","$2, $1",$argn);
```

Run as pipe with `-nF`.